# JQuery 2 runat:server

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to get mouse coordinated from asp.net page in to run at server "TextBox".

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
        $('#status').html(e.pageX + ', ' + e.pageY);
    });
})
```

Working

```
<h2 id="status">
0, 0
</h2>
```

Needed

```
<asp:TextBox ID="status" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

And I can't understand where the error is and why is not working.

Comment: your Jquery code is correct but when ur textbox control is render by server so ur control id is change so jquery not able to find ur textbox ..

Answer (score 1):

use a cssClass or dont use a ASP.net controller for it

```
<asp:TextBox ID="status" runat="server" cssClass="status" />
```

and use a class selector (and set its value, not html):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
        $('.status').val(e.pageX + ', ' + e.pageY);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You better add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to your asp.net control so that the ID will not change on run time

```
<asp:TextBox ID="status" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a `ClientID` because ur control id change when it render by server

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
        $('#'+'<%=status.ClientID %>').html(e.pageX + ', ' + e.pageY);
    });
})
```